Multi module spring boot project, RestController is not scanned
I am starting a new Spring Boot application using spring boot 3.2.4. this application has the following module structure
parent
lmi
app
max
Parent pom:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <properties>
        <project.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.think.positive</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>





    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <modules>
        <module>lmi</module>
        <module>max</module>
        <module>app</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.think.positive</mainClass>
                    <outputDirectory>out</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



lmi pom:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.think.positive</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>lmi</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



app pom:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.think.positive</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



</project>



max POM:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.think.positive</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>max</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



</project>



In each project, I have controller package where all REST related controllers should be.
The main class where spring kicks in located in parent.
The issue is, RestControllers located in other modules other than the parent module are not getting scanned and hence I am getting no response in my tests.
I tried using scanBasePackages and it did not help
Another thing that I tried was to explicitly tell the name of the class of the rest controller however this required to add dependency of the child module in the parent causing for cyclic dependency, so this is not a solution.
I read many articles and many SO questions, some did not represent my scenario and some suggested solutions did not helped, hence I am asking again here.
Main goal, having multiple Rest controllers across modules and manage to invoke them.
